# Issue with mysql Partitioning

Tags: mysql, partitioning, large-data

I have done some tests to study about partitioning , so that I can implement it to my live database that is having large data.

Step 1:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tr (id INT, name VARCHAR(50), purchased DATE)
PARTITION BY RANGE(year(purchased))
(
PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (1990),
PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (1995),
PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2000),
PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (2005),
PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (2010),
PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (2015),
PARTITION pmax VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

Setp 2:

```sql
INSERT INTO tr VALUES
(1, 'Store1', '2003-10-15'),
(2, 'Store1', '1997-11-05'),
(3, 'Store1', '2009-03-10'),
(4, 'Store2', '1989-01-10'),
(5, 'Store1', '2014-05-09'),
(6, 'Store1', '1987-06-05'),
(7, 'Store3', '2011-11-22'),
(8, 'Store3', '1992-08-04'),
(9, 'Store4', '2006-09-16'),
(10, 'Store4', '1998-12-25');
```

Step 3:

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tr WHERE purchased BETWEEN '1987-06-05' AND '1989-01-10';
```

in this step when am retriving data it only using p0 partition which is correct.

Setp 4:

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tr WHERE YEAR(purchased) BETWEEN 1987 AND 1989;
```

in this step I just changed the where query to check the data based on year only not a full date.Here in this case the query searching in whole partition.

I don't understand why it is working like this.Any oneis familair with this issue please explain.

Comment: Although partitioning uses the expression `YEAR(purchase)`, it is performed by the value of the `purchase` column. The fact that the expression in the condition matches literally does not change anything. The partitioning means not "compare the expression value with the value in partitioning index" but "apply partitioning expression to the value". The value in the condition is `YEAR(purchased)`, and applying the partitioning expression to it will give `year(YEAR(purchased))` which obviously makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Function calls, even as simple as `YEAR(x)` are not sargable.  The net effect is that they cannot be effectively used with `INDEXes` or `PARTITIONing`.

If your `SELECT` in "step 3" is realistic, then the Partitioning will be no faster than having `INDEX(purchased)` on a non-partitioned table.

If you will be deleting 'old' data after some number of years, then this is one good use for Partitioning -- namely that `DROP PARTITION` is faster than `DELETE`.  Still, you need to formulate the queries as a range of dates, not using any functions.

See also [*Partition*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)